# Is there any option to export only two columns in grocery-crud.. i don't want to export all columns

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

Is there any option to export only two columns in grocery-crud. I don't want to export all   columns.

Comment: I Founded the answer. just now. 
if ($this->uri->segment(3) == "export") {
$crud->columns('code','name');
}
else{
$crud->columns('code','name','email','phone');
}

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do it is to use the `getState()` method

```
$state = $crud->getState();

if ($state == 'export' || $state == 'print') {
    $crud->columns('first_name','last_name','email');
} else {
    $crud->columns('first_name','last_name','email','phone','city','country');
}
```

Below you can find a full code example :

```
function example1()
{
    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

    $crud->set_table('customers');
    $crud->set_subject('Customer');
    $crud->required_fields('first_name', 'last_name','email');

    $state = $crud->getState();

    if ($state == 'export' || $state == 'print') {
        $crud->columns('first_name','last_name','email');
    } else {
        $crud->columns('first_name','last_name','email','phone','city','country');
    }

    $output = $crud->render();

    $this->_example_output($output);
}
```

Comment: This is giving me error Use of undefined constant state - assumed 'state'